# Trouble with Variable value in function

Tags: javascript

I have the following script where a variable gets its value from an input field, however when I run my function its not working, returns nothing. Im new to JS so im unsure if it needs to be part of a function *even though Ive tried this with no luck) or what...

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Variables

// Content/SLA
var ContentMinutes = '';
var ContentMinutesSelector; // Switch Case
var ServiceLevel = 5;
var NoOfFrames = 2;

// Render Time (Hairier the Better)
var AvgFrameRenderTime = '';
var AvgFrameRenderTimeSelector = 10; // Switch Case
var CoresInTest = document.getElementById('CoresInTest').value;

// Other
var EstimatedCoreHours = NoOfFrames * CoresInTest * AvgFrameRenderTimeSelector;

// Cost Estimate
var CostEstimate = ServiceLevel * EstimatedCoreHours;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//  Functions

function CalculateEstimate() {  
// Estimate Cost
parseInt(document.getElementById("PriceEstimate").innerHTML=CostEstimate.toFixed(2));

// Estimate Core Hours
parseInt(document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").innerHTML=EstimatedCoreHours.toFixed(    2));
}
```

my PriceEstimate and EstimatedCoreHours fields are both just empty divs, `<div id="EstimatedCoreHours"></div>`, My calculations work if i define a value for the variable as opposed to `document.getElementById` so I believe I must need to run a function or something to update all the vartiables?

But if I set...

```
var CoresInTest = document.getElementById('CoresInTest').value;
```

to

```
var CoresInTest = 10;
```

Then it works fine...

Its not actually my return, the problem is my variables arent calling, IF i define them with a number then it works.

Comment: If `PriceEstimate` or `EstimatedCoreHours` are input fields (`<input type="text"/>`), you should use `.value` and not `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Something I noted, you're calling parseInt, but you're not taking the value it returns. And your method doesn't actually have any return statements, so it's not going to return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to do something like this, if you are looking to get calculated data in your div.

```
document.getElementById("PriceEstimate").innerHTML=parseInt(CostEstimate.toFixed(2));    
// Estimate Core Hours
document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").innerHTML=parseInt(EstimatedCoreHours.toFixed(2));
```

---

If `var CoresInTest = 10;` works fine, then your code is placed wrong.

What element is `CoresInTest`? is it a text field? and if so is this script placed or called before the element renders? then you will have to reinitialize that variable.

Comment: Not sure what that changes.  Not sure why the author has 'parseInt' and 'toFixed' together.  The requirement is either integer or 2 decimal places, I'm guessing it's 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

If PriceEstimate and EstimatedCoreHours are  elements you should use the value property
this might work for you:

```
document.getElementById("PriceEstimate").value=parseInt(CostEstimate.toFixed(2),10);    
document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").value=parseInt(EstimatedCoreHours.toFixed(2),10);
```

Comment: Question says they're DIV elements.  Not form fields.

Answer (score 0):

If `var CoresInTest = 10;` makes it work fine, then it must be something to do with `document.getElementById('CoresInTest').value` - so why isn't that working?  Is it a drop down list?  Instead of us guessing, tell us.